# "didn't tell" vs "wouldn't tell"

Tags: past-tense

What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

> I asked where she kept her jewellery, but she **didn't tell** me where.
>
> I asked where she kept her jewellery, but she **wouldn't tell** me where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of **wouldn't** implies an unwillingness, whereas **didn't** doesn't have that same implication. In both cases you still don't know where she keeps her jewelry. Using "wouldn't" means that she refused to tell you. Using "didn't" could also mean that, but it could also mean that she didn't hear you, or she got confused what you were asking, or any number of other things.

If you take the sentence "she wouldn't tell me where she kept her jewelry", that implies that you asked and she refused to answer. If you take "she didn't tell me where she kept her jewelry", that just implies a lack of information, which you may or may not have asked about.